# how to start tomcat in Jenkins job using shell script?

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, continuous-integration, devops, jenkins-cli

I have jenkins installed in my linux machine, in that under http://172.19.113.104:8080/jenkinsjob/RBT/configure/  >  Build  >  Execute shell

I added **sh -x /opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel/bin/startup.sh** to make tomcat up.

but tomcat not coming up but if I run same command in linux machine terminal directly tomcat coming up !

**Jenkins console output log** :

- os400=false
- darwin=false
- case "`uname`" in
  ++ uname
- PRG=/opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel/bin/startup.sh
- '[' -h /opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel/bin/startup.sh ']'
  ++ dirname /opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel/bin/startup.sh
- PRGDIR=/opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel/bin
- EXECUTABLE=catalina.sh
- false
- '[' '!' -x /opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel/bin/catalina.sh ']'
- exec /opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel/bin/catalina.sh start

**Below is trace when ran in linux terminal and tomcat came up**

[root@rbtstaging ~]# sh -x /opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel/bin/startup.sh 
+ os400=false
+ darwin=false
+ case "`uname`" in
++ uname
+ PRG=/opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel/bin/startup.sh
+ '[' -h /opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel/bin/startup.sh ']'
++ dirname /opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel/bin/startup.sh
+ PRGDIR=/opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel/bin
+ EXECUTABLE=catalina.sh
+ false
+ '[' '!' -x /opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel/bin/catalina.sh ']'
+ exec /opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel/bin/catalina.sh start
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel/bin/bootstrap.jar

Please help..!

In jenkins tried after adding below but no use.

export CATALINA_BASE='/opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel'

export CATALINA_BASE='/opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel'

Comment: Is the user jenkins using to run the script have permission to access/execute tomcat? Are there any errors (check /var/log/syslog)?

Comment: Hi Alex, No no errors in syslog and I didnt create any user for jenkins, please tell how you are starting your tomcat in your jenkins kindly

Comment: We use 'service tomcat8 start' command as root user.

Answer (score 1):

Install "Pipeline Keep Running" plugin and add script to keepRunning function in Jenkinsfile Start stage.

keepRunning {
sh '/usr/local/apache-tomact/bin/startup.sh }

Ref: https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-keep-running-step/

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer Hurrayyy.....!

In your script above tomcat start command i.e sh /opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel/bin/startup.sh you have to add **export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe**

```
export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
sh /opt/WebService/7.9SP2_Airtel/bin/startup.sh
```

After adding this tomcat coming up. Lot thanks to every one who ever considered my issue.